# Console does not display the small s with caron when converted to ISO 8859-1

Tags: c#, encoding, console, iso-8859-1, windows-1252

My application receives Integer Values for ISO 8859-1 Chars over TCP and should display it for testing in the console. For converting the Int/Bytes to ISO 8859-1 strings, I took the code from the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666385/how-can-i-convert-extended-ascii-to-a-system-string):

```
var e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
var s = e.GetString(new byte[] { 189 });
```

Its working fine for example with a value of *189* which is *½* in ISO 8859-1. But in my test, I got a Byte with the value of `154` which is *š* (Latin small letter S with caron) according to [this site](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

The Problem is that it doesnt display it on the console, its just displays a Question mark like that:
[image]
and the Debugger shows only a plain string:[image]
**What could be the error?**
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce. In LinqPad `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(new byte[] { 189 })` produces `½`.

Comment: This is not a C# problem *per se*, I'm revising the title.

Comment: Does that standard actually define that value of 154? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 doesn't look like it;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here;  ISO/IEC 8859-1 does not define values between 126 and 159. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

this works;

```
  var e = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
  var s = e.GetString(new byte[] { 154 });

  Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");

  Console.WriteLine(s);
```

I believe Windows-1252 is prefered;

> ...however the draft HTML 5 specification requires that documents
>   advertised as ISO-8859-1 actually be parsed with the Windows-1252
>   encoding.[2])

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: Yep, „š” is not defined in ISO 8859-1. It is in ISO 8859-2 at codepoint 185.

Comment: Hmm maybe theres a workaround? Because in C++ std::char does display š when its value is 154.

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls: then what you use is not ISO 8859-1. Maybe it is some platform-specific extention?