# c# get decimal value of unicode

Tags: c#

Language: `c#`

Im struggling to convert some data
My device sends to PC the humble byte 0xbc(188 decimal)
The serial port sees it as the char "?" or 0x3f in hexadecimal
i think I have tried all conversion functions. I don't see how  0xbc translates to 0x3f ;

After seeing this I set the encoding of serial port to

```
ComPort.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
```

but no result; the same thing happens

I have tried

```
byte[] b=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(recievedData);
```

where recievedData is 
    `recievedData = ComPort.ReadExisting();` ( recievedData is a string)

Im sure it is a conversion problem but I'm stuck

```
int  c=char.ConvertToUtf32(recievedData,0) //does not work
```

What to do in order to have 0xbc' string equivalent in recievedData ?

Comment: make sure the baud rate of receiving and sending ports are equal

Comment: What is the result you expect? The number 188 to be in the `c` variable? Because in that case you shouldn't use Text conversions

Comment: If you want something else as the result, the extended ascii value for `0xBC` is ¼ - to get this you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666385/how-can-i-convert-extended-ascii-to-a-system-string

Comment: @Bojan Where is "extended ASCII" defined? Do you mean the "ISO/IEC 8859-1" encoding (aka "Latin 1")?

Comment: @MatthewWatson thats the encoding I meant, yes

Comment: @fionut Try using `Encoding.Default` rather than `Encoding.ASCII`.

Comment: You are doing it wrong.  Do **not** use the SerialPort methods that read a string.  It is not a string, the device is sending binary data.  Use the Read() method instead.  Or you got the configuration wrong and the data is getting corrupted, that's possible as well.  Look in the device's programming manual to make sure.

Comment: the device is sending mixed data; strings; and some other not printable values like 0xbc; the communication is fine; when the device sends strings to pc ; the pc sees exactly what the device is sending. the problem is for other values; with no printable meaning

Comment: @MatthewWatson i used the default encoding the same thing happened; after that i changed to ASCII